# Updating user in Django with Backbone.js and Tastypie

Tags: django, backbone.js, tastypie

What is a proper way of updating Django's User attributes (particularly `password` and `email`) using Backbone and Tastypie?

In general what is a good workflow from API standpoint in those two cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of "one-field" updates is handled by the PATCH HTTP verb. So you should do an Ajax request with this method and the data you want to update.

In curl, it'd be:

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PATCH --data '{"email": "new@email.com"}' "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/user/1/"
```

About Backbone, it's not a requirement. You can keep a User model and use `sync` method, but with a `Jquery.ajax()` call it would be enough.

Jquery:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'PATCH',
  url: http://localhost:8000/api/v1/user/1/,
  data: "{'email': 'new@email.com'}",
  success: function(){/* your logic */},
  contentType: "application/json"
});
```

Comment: Yeah, this is clear. But I'm talking about more general stuff. Like what will be the logic for updating the email field via API. It usually makes sense to do some email confirmation before updating.

Comment: If you created your UserResource from the ModelResource class, you don't need to do anything. Regardign the confirmation, that's something you have to handle in your view. The API is the last step in any process.

Comment: PATCH is the right verb to invoke a partial update. Under the hood, Tastypie reads the entire object and issue an update (PUT).  You must create your view (in this case with HTML and JS) and ask a confirmation from your user. Once it's accepted you use the API to modify the data.